# In Walden did Thoreau use the term "animal products" in our modern sense?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In Chapter "Winter animals" Thoreau writes in a very eloquent way about partridges and hares. But then he sounds a bit rough and rude. The last paragraph of the chapter starts with:

> What is a country without rabbits and partridges?
>   They are among the most simple and indigenous animal
>   products; ancient and venerable families known to antiquity
>   as to modern times; of the very hue and substance
>   of Nature, nearest allied to leaves and to the ground,—and
>   to one another; it is either winged or it is legged.

Webster's Dictionary defines an animal product as ["a product made from animal material"](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/animal%20Product)

Does he really name hares and partridges "animal products" in today's contemporary meaning? How one should understand the phrase properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand Thoreau's phrase to mean that these are animals that are products (of the environment), rather than products made from animals.

Rabbits and partridges are both edible, and it seems likely that Thoreau would have trapped or hunted them for food while living at Walden Pond (although possibly not, as he was a some-times vegetarian).

In another part of *Walden*, he mentions an unnamed visitor to his cabin who is a hunter, and mentions some of the things that could be hunted in the area:

> [My visitor] would say, as he went by in the morning, “How thick the pigeons
>   are! If working every day were not my trade, I could get all the meat
>   I should want by hunting,—pigeons, woodchucks, rabbits, partridges,—by
>   gosh! I could get all I should want for a week in one day.”

So rabbits and partridges were literally products (things produced by) the countryside that he (or others) made use of for sustenance.

Comment: From honey and milk to wool and silk, from methane and manure to coral reefs and beaver ponds: across the ever-increasing gulfs separating our own times from *Walden*’s, we can little more than speculate whether Thoreau considered all such as these to be *the **produce** of animals* in quite the same way as we ourselves now hold them to be things produced “by” animals.

Comment: Yes, animals produced by the countryside. Not dead meat.